# OS X (10.11)—accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType always returns false

Tags: macos, swift, twitter

Relatively new to OS X development, working on porting a simple Twitter tool from iOS to the desktop and have come across a bug(?)/change in expected behavior in the Accounts framework.

`accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType`, I'm always getting back false, regardless of which button I choose in the authorization dialogue.

```
func fetch(){
    let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
    let accountType = accountStore.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)

    accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(accountType, options: nil) { (granted : Bool, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        print(granted)
    }
}
```

Is there a complication on OS X that doesn't exist in iOS? Or is this a bug in the GM?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Thus far, I have not. Hoping a point release solves. Works in Yosemite.

Comment: Any solution to this yet?